# Symfony 2 logger

Tags: symfony

Please help me with my problem. I am new with symfony 2 and i can't resolve my problem alone. I wan't to see my variable value in symfony 2 console and i read that it can be resolved with logger but when i use logger i see the type of my variable but i wan't to see a value of my variable. Have can i see it ???

```
public function helloAction($name)
{   
    $a = array('b' => 'ffsddsfs');
    $logger = $this->get('logger')->info($a);
    return array('name' => $name, 'a' => $a);
}
```

result.

```
INFO - Array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try it with this

```
$logger = $this->get('logger')->info(var_export($a, true));
```

This makes a string from your array and then the logger should be able to print the variable!

Answer (score 1):

Your logger expected string (see [docs](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Logger.php#L435)) and you gave array, so php by default converted array type to string `Array`. You should use function for making string from your array, ex: [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php). So you shold try this one:

```
$logger = $this->get('logger')->info(print_r($a));
```